# Grouping Unique Strings in a Column and Performing Function On Separate Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe, I have the column "away_lineup" which contains groupings of 5 strings as well as a "play_length" column that has a time duration value for each row. I know that np.unique can detect unique string values and the np.sum value adds values in a column, but how do I use a function like np.unique to detect each unique string and sum the values of "play_length" that the string occurs in a row with?

```
away_lineup                                                                play_length
0  Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons     0:00:05
1  Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons     0:00:10
2  Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons     0:00:20
3  Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons     0:00:07
4  Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons     0:00:25
5  Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, JJ Redick       0:00:14
```

My desired output would be something like

```
player              play_length
Dario Saric             0:01:21
Robert Covington        0:01:21
Joel Embiid             0:01:21
Markelle Fultz          0:01:21
Ben Simmons             0:01:07
JJ Redick               0:00:14
```

Where unique names are pulled from "away_lineup", stored in a new column "player", and the rows where the player value are present have their "play_length" values added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use explode and group by like this

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## create dummy data
arr = [("Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons", "00:00:05"),
("Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons", "00:00:10"),
("Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons", "00:00:20"),
("Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons", "00:00:07"),
("Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, Ben Simmons", "00:00:25"),
("Dario Saric, Robert Covington, Joel Embiid, Markelle Fultz, JJ Redick", "00:00:14"),]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["Player", "Play Time"])
df["Play Time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Play Time"])

## Solution
df["Player"] = df["Player"].str.split(",")
df.explode("Player").groupby("Player").sum()
```

**output**

```
            Play Time
Player  
Ben Simmons 00:01:07
JJ Redick   00:00:14
Joel Embiid 00:01:21
Markelle Fultz  00:01:21
Robert Covington    00:01:21
Dario Saric 00:01:21
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

*Note*: `pandas.DataFrame.explode` is available with `pandas` >= 0.25

```
df['away_lineup'] = df['away_lineup'].str.split(', ')
df['play_length'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['play_length'])
new_df = df.explode('away_lineup').groupby('away_lineup').sum()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                 play_length
away_lineup                 
Ben Simmons         00:01:07
Dario Saric         00:01:21
JJ Redick           00:00:14
Joel Embiid         00:01:21
Markelle Fultz      00:01:21
Robert Covington    00:01:21
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your pandas does not support `explode`:

```
df['play_length'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['play_length'])

new_df = pd.concat((df[['play_length']], 
                    df['away_lineup'].str.split(',\s*', expand=True)), 
                   axis=1)

(new_df.melt(id_vars=['play_length'], 
             value_vars=new_df.columns[1:], 
             value_name='artist')
   .groupby('artist').play_length.sum()
)
```

Output:

```
artist
Ben Simmons        00:01:07
Dario Saric        00:01:21
JJ Redick          00:00:14
Joel Embiid        00:01:21
Markelle Fultz     00:01:21
Robert Covington   00:01:21
Name: play_length, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Worked in conjunction with @Dev Kadka's answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the trick of `get_dummies`

```
#df['play_length'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['play_length'])

df.away_lineup.str.get_dummies(',').mul(df.play_length,0).sum()
Out[372]: 
 Ben Simmons        00:01:07
 JJ Redick          00:00:14
 Joel Embiid        00:01:21
 Markelle Fultz     00:01:21
 Robert Covington   00:01:21
 Dario Saric        00:01:21
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I get this error AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @SmallChimp you need to show us the data by dict , since we do not know what kind of data type you have in your column

Comment: My apologies @WeNYoBen, 'away_lineup' and 'play_length' are stored as a "non-null object." Do they need to be converted to something else? I'm sorry if I'm not answering your question fully.